# Does integrability over a rectangular region implies continuity?

Tags: integration, continuity, riemann-integration

Hello I tried but stuck in this question. I think an integrable function might be not continious.

> Let $R = [a_1,b_1]\times...\times[a_n,b_n]$ be an $n$-dimensional rectangular region and $f: R \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. For each $x = (x_1,...,x_n)\in R$, define $R_x$ to be $[a_1,x_1]\times ... \times [a_n,x_n]$. Suppose 
>   $$F(x) = \int_{R_x}fdV$$
>   Show that the function $F: R \to\mathbb R$ is continious.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: It is easy to come up with integrable functions that are not continuous; take any linear function with a jump discontinuity, for example. In your expression, though, we are assuming that $f$ is integrable, not $F$. $f$ may very well be discontinuous, but $F$ has much stronger conditions on it than $f$.

Comment: If you are stuck, I suggest trying it for $n = 1$; if you are still unable to prove it in that case, you could add some detail to your question explaining where you are having trouble.